# Photoshop resizing image to a set parameter without skewing

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm using Adobe Photoshop CC 2015. My boss sent me a slew of poster images that he wants resized, but he doesn't want them skewed or cropped in any way. For example, one of the files is 36" by 24". He wants it resized to 58 &3/8" by 52" without stretching/skewing it or cropping it.

How is this even possible?

Comment: Hi Diggums, welcome to GD.SE! It is not possible. If the enlargement is not the same ratio as the starting point then you have to either crop or distort the image. The only other option is to make the enlarged graphic the same ratio as 36x24. Or in your case you could make the image fit the destination space and have blank spaces on top and below the image.

Comment: See? That's exactly what I thought. It doesn't seem physically possible. X(

but he is adamant that there is a way to do so using "vectors". 
i'm not familiar with this process but I highly doubt that it can supersede the laws of physics.

Comment: Tell your boss the options: Crop the image, fit media to destination space and have blank spaces above and below or transform the image to fit which I advise you don't do. If you want to explain it simply just say you have a 3" W x 2" H image and you have to fit it in a 6" W x 6" H  frame. if you enlarge it to the maximum space of 6", you will have 2" of blank space vertically. If you make the height 6", you will have to crop 3" from the width.

Answer (score 1):

While it’s really not possible to do what you want in the way your boss is asking, you could look at using an app like [iResizer](https://www.iresizer.com). While it won’t completely solve your problem, it might get you closer to what your boss wants.

I’ve used it on several projects before with great results, and my end clients were very happy with what they thought they wanted.

If you do try the [iResizer](https://www.iresizer.com) app, you will want to try resizing each image several times with different maskings (masks are used to define areas that will not distort when the image is re-sized), then choose the best result out of about 3 or 4 different run throughs.

[image: 2]

Also, you might want to let your boss know that raster images (pixels based, photos, scanned images, images created within Photoshop) are not vectors (what you would create in Illustrator) and as such will typically suffer from some distortion when upsized.